# Write `4 : '$ x (<") y'` tacitly

Tags: j

How can I write the `frame` function tacitly? (From "Learning J" Ch 7)

I'm using the `f x g y = x f@:g y` composition scheme from Ch 8 , but it's not working. My guess is because `<"` has no natural rank?

```
x=.1
y=.i.2 3 4
f=.$
g=.<"

frame_e=.4 :'f x g y'
frame_t=.f@:g
x frame_e y         NB. -> 2 3, which is the x-frame of y
x frame_t y         NB. -> domain error

NB. No natural rank
g b.0               NB. -> syntax error
0 g b.0             NB. -> 0 0 0
```

I confirmed the pattern works as I expected with other functions.

```
x=.1
y=.i.2 3 4
f=.+/
g=.*

f x g y             NB. -> equiv of 12+2*i.3 4
x f@:g y            NB. -> same
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tacitly, I would do it using

```
   framet=. {. $
   2 framet i. 2 3 4
2 3
```

but that does not really get to the root of your question, does it?

The issue is really the way that `g` is defined:

```
g=.<"
```

This does not make `g` a verb, but an adverb. It does use the `x` in the explicit definition to create a verb, but it needs to do this before it uses that verb to evaluate y. As far as I know, J does not allow you to stage these processes. As you have seen the pattern does work when `f` and `g` are actually verbs.

I find tacit programming elegant, but it can be slower at some things and there are areas where it is limited.

I am hoping that someone can provide a better answer, so that I may learn as well.

Comment: debug/dissect points this problem out for the `@:` version: `domain error: operands to @: must be verbs`

Comment: The additional explanation was very helpful. I'll try to make sure my tacit definitions only include things that reduce to actual verbs.

Comment: When can tacit verbs be slower? If the question is covered in Learning J or JforC, then no worries; I'll get to it soon enough. (;

Comment: You pretty much have to check your definitions from time to time using `timespacex` which is a verb that takes a character list as its right argument and an integer n as its left argument and returns the average time of the n repeated executions of the character list and the space used in bytes. Most often I think it happens when special code has not been written for some tacit combinations.

Comment: Thanks, bob. I just came across special code / special combinations yesterday. I'll be sure to run phrases through `timespacex` as I go.